# .htaccess internal redirect not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried doing some .htaccess redirects for internal pages but they are not working for me. This is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule articles articles/how-to-play-piano [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also tried this outside `<IfModule>` but not working:

```
Redirect 301 http://www.domain.com/articles http://www.domain.com/articles/how-to-play-piano
```

and

```
Redirect 301 /articles http://www.domain.com/articles/how-to-play-piano
```

Comment: Did you try commenting out your `RewriteRule` code before trying the `Redirect 301` line? There could be some conflicts between what you have in the IfModule and what you're 301 line is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is wrong for `articles` rule and will cause infinite looping. To fix that you need to use anchors `^ and $`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^articles/?$ articles/how-to-play-piano [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Great. That seems to work. Thanks. However after the redirect, the url is still showing `http://www.domain.com/articles`. Is it possible to change the browser url to `http://www.domain.com/articles/how-to-play-piano` instead? It's perhaps not redirecting. It's just rewriting the URL?

Comment: Ok I added `R=301` back in that rule. fyi now it is called external redirect instead of an internal one.